# vb.net: is it possible to import FreeImage.dll to vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, dll, dllimport, tga

I need to read\write tga files from vb,
I found TargaImage.dll, nice lib but it allows only read tga.
I found FreeImage, tryed to import it in vb, but it says:

`FreeImage.dll could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.`

I think I have to use , but absolutly dont know anything.
help plz:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the way the distribution works, you have two options:

First, you could call the functions in the DLL directly using `<DllImport>` attributes. This is going to require a lot of learning of how to make calls to unmanaged DLLs, passing the right values, etc. Which is why I suggest the second option.

The second option is, you can use the .NET Wrapper project that is included in the distribution. If you're using a version of Visual Studio that supports multiple programming languages, just add the wrapper project to your solution and reference the wrapper project from the project that needs to use it.

If you're using Visual Studio Express, you won't be able to add a C# project to a VB solution. I'd suggest downloading C# Express, compiling the wrapper project, and then adding the compiled DLL to your VB.Net project.

Comment: I have C# Express 2010, can you say where i can got wrapper project?

Comment: @0867532 It's in FreeImage\Wrapper\FreeImage.NET\cs

Comment: :( i open \FreeImage\Wrapper\FreeImage.NET\cs\FreeImage.NET.vsSolution  with C#EXPRESS and got 439 errors while compile or debug...

Comment: @0867532 If, in Solution Explorer, you remove all the projects except for `Library.2005`, set it to Release insted of Debug, and then build it, hopefully you will end up with the required files in the bin\Release directory. (You might be able to just build the Library.2005 project - I had already removed the other projects before trying to build.)